# Wordpress post date change everyday

Tags: wordpress, date, post

i got some problem with my blog.
Why everyday, every date of every post change to the current date??

I search in every setting of wordpress blog but i don't find anything.

Please someone can help me with this issue??

Best regards

Comment: Did you contact Wordpress support?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your own theme then open find `current_time()` function in your theme pages and replace with `get_the_time()` function.

Please [refere](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)